# Редактирование контента на сайте на Джанго

Tags: django

Сайт на django. Нет доступа в админку (бывший фрилансер не отдал его и пропал с концами).
Имеется доступ к хостингу и домену.
Как можно отредактировать текст на сайте?
Какие пути решения имеются?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

1. Зайти на сервер
2. Найти папку с проектом
3. Активировать виртуальное окружение
4. Прописать python manage.py createsuperuser и создать суперпользователя, у него будет доступ к админке
   Также можно залезть в базу и поправить статус у уже существующего пользователя
   Надеюсь помог или навел на нужные мысли :)